# How to create new DWG from existing DWG Files?

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

I have a web application created using three.js that can create architectural linings, wood claddings and batten screenings. Our 3d Models are from created using Blender since we can't upload autocad files to threejs.

Can autodesk forge give me the ability to create new DWG from my existing DWG files?

for example, I have around separate 5 dwg files and using a web app, I need to put those 5 into 1 dwg file only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this using the [Design Automation API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2): this is a backend technology that allows you to process AutoCAD jobs in the Cloud. You need some AutoCAD API programming skills to use it.

You can then use the [Model Derivatives API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/) to convert the resulting dwg(s) into a viewable format that can easily be loaded into the [Forge Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2).